# WinAPI: изменение даты создания файла на текущую, и вывод её в Listbox

Tags: winapi, файлы, c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь разобраться c `WinAPI`. Нужно изменить время создание файлов в папке на текущее время, а затем вывести имена файлов и дату в `List Box`. Удалось только вывести имена файлов. Пробовал менять дату с помощью `SetFileTime()`, но она не меняется.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hf = FindFirstFile("\\*", &FindFileData);

do {
    // Если не директория
    if(!(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
        // Вывод имени файла в ListBox
        SendDlgItemMessage(
            p->hDlg,
            IDC_LIST1,
            LB_ADDSTRING,
            NULL,
            (LPARAM)FindFileData.cFileName
        ); 
    }

}
while(FindNextFile(hf,&FindFileData) != 0);

FindClose(hf);
```

Comment: >Пробовал менять дату с помощью SetFileTime(), но она не меняется.

Показывайте, как пробовали.  
 --  
Вот Ваш пример: [Changing a File Time to the Current Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ms724205(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: BOOL SetFileToCurrentTime(HANDLE hFile)
{
  FILETIME ft;
  SYSTEMTIME st;

  GetSystemTime(&st);                 // получить текущее время
  SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);     // преобразовать в файловый формат
  return SetFileTime(hFile,           // установить дату/время модификации файла
              &ft, (LPFILETIME) NULL, (LPFILETIME) NULL);
}

Comment: strcat_s(dispname,"\\*");
 
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
 
HANDLE hf; 
 
hf = FindFirstFile(dispname,&FindFileData);

 
do 
{
  //Если не директория
  
if(!(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) 
{

   
SendDlgItemMessage(p->hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING,NULL,(LPARAM)FindFileData.cFileName);
   
   
if(SetFileToCurrentTime(hf))
    
SendDlgItemMessage(p->hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)TEXT("Done!"));

   
   

  
}

 
}
 
while(FindNextFile(hf,&FindFileData) != 0);
 
FindClose(hf);

Comment: >if(SetFileToCurrentTime(hf))...

`hf` - это не файловый дескриптор, отсюда и ошибка. Файловый дескриптор возвращает `CreateFile`

Comment: Добавил в цикл:

    hOF = (HANDLE)CreateFile(FindFileData.cFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
   
       if(SetFileToCurrentTime(hOF))
        SendDlgItemMessage(p->hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)TEXT("Done!"));

       CloseHandle(hOF);

Но все равно не меняет дату.

Comment: В `FindFileData.cFileName` хранится только имя файла, а `CreateFile` требует **путь** к файлу, т.е. `CreateFile` у Вас всегда возвращает `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, вот и "не меняет".  
 --  
Вам нужно собрать нормальный путь перед вызовом `CreateFile`.